# How to write a PHP variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

This is my JavaScript function:

```
    $('.btn-setting').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

And this is how I call it in PHP file:

```
   <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">
```

My question is: how to pass a variable in:

```
   $('#myModal<?php $variable ?>').modal('show');
```

And call it in a PHP file like this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal<?php echo $variable ;>?" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">
```

Comment: You need to `echo` the PHP variables. According to the vampires :)

Comment: If you have short tags enabled, you can use `<?=$variable;?>`.

Answer (score 1):

In your php file, you need echo variable in your script, like

```
<script>
$('#myModal<?php echo $variable; ?>').modal('show');
</script>
```

If you echo in `.js` file, it doesn't work

**Update answer**

In html section of `php` file you need echo `variable` like below

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal<?=$variable?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Comment: & how i call it in php file    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">

Comment: you need insert a `<script>` tag in php file and write your javascript code in

Comment: yes i know but i mean when i call it in div tag its  in id="myModal" how i call it when its in 'id'

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#myModal<?php echo $variable; ?>').modal('show');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use echo function

```
   $('#myModal<?php echo $variable ?>').modal('show');
```

Answer (score 0):

Php give you [echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) (`Output one or more strings`) for the task.

```
$('#myModal<?php echo $variable; ?>').modal('show');
```